# Just how conservative is the voting reversal script?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I know that stack exchange runs a daily automated script that reverses obvious serial voting. I also know that the fine print of how this script is tuned is relatively secret to prevent gaming it.

Lately I've been digging for serial voters and found some truly astonishing and obvious cases (Like, you look at it and it's immediately clear what's happening - and that is just from the public facing data) that hadn't been touched by the script.

I know from other meta posts that the script is tuned very conservatively to avoid many false positives, but it got me thinking that there are *so many* obvious cases that the script doesn't catch. Maybe it's in need of some retuning to reflect current user behavior.

Some examples of cases the script didn't catch:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now these are just 3 of dozens of obvious-to-the-eye-and-a-data-analyzing-tool (even though I already tune my own means of finding them conservatively on account of all the data I can't see since I'm not a mod) cases that go unreversed every week. I don't need to be a moderator or CM to see that this is pretty obvious, which makes me wonder:

Does the serial voting script need retuning to keep up with the times?

Comment: I've already raised the issue with the CM team, given that you are finding so many cases for us to send to them.

Comment: The reversal of serial voting does not remove the reputation entries. I assume the screenshots are not from your own profile, and I'm not sure if you can see the voting reversal entry on another person's profile?

Comment: @Stijn You can see them, the reversals show as negative reputation entries. Also, none of the screenshots above have been reversed. I only snipshotted the profiles to not publicly name & shame these users, especially since one can be serially upvoted without one's consent.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If my records are correct, there are still _hundreds_ of unreversed cases from further back then a month or two. I've only started flagging these 3 weeks ago, so anything from significantly before that I haven't even looked into yet, but I don't exactly want to flood you guys with 100 custom flags a day for a week straight. As it lies now, there's about 25 give or take a couple cases a week that I can easily find that go unreversed, and that's using just the public facing data I have access to. I'd bet there's a couple dozen more you could get at very easily.

Comment: @Stijn: Magisch has been flagging legitimate cases for us. So far, all such flags that we handled have been found helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters re: your first comment. If wanted, I can explain the methodology used to find these completly, but I'd rather not in public, since people could use this to harass / witch hunt. But it's probably not necessary as there's nothing that I (a complete scrub in data analysis)  can do that SO can't

Comment: @Magisch: you could email that to the CMs; use the 'contact us' link and share it there!

Comment: Hmya, making it look like an answer is a fantastic one in a heavily visited tag is not rocket science.  If SO were a bank then it would have gone bankrupt fifty times already.  If you want to commit fraud and get away with then you'd better get the heck out of town and change your name.  Users like this always get caught, eventually, justice is merely delayed.

Comment: @HansPassant I have more then 1000 cases like this from merely the last 400 days sitting here that haven't been touched that suggest otherwise. And this is with my pretty stupid layman's attempt at data analysis. Also, these users don't work by having 5 accounts upvote their 1 answer, they spread like 10 upvotes across 10 answers and call it a day.

Comment: On 6.7 million users, a 0.015% latency is not a big one.  Cheating is also a rather boring way to gain rep, they only get caught if they continue to contribute.  Sounds like you want to show off your bot, consider making it smart enough to also flag the post.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not a bot. I'm nowhere near smart enough to write a bot for this. Atm, I'm doing all of this by hand. And ideally someone from the team would fine-tune the reversal script to get those. Even if I casted the flags automatically, mods would still have to escalate and a CM would still have to process every single one of them.

Comment: I flagged only a couple of serial downvotes on my own rep.  Now I feel totally inadequate:)

Comment: @HansPassant downvoting is much more popular. Unfortunatelly, the script isn't perfect there too.

Comment: @xenteros I also have a thing to catch uncaught serial downvoting, it happens much, _much_ less often though, at least in obvious patterns

Comment: @Magisch I'm happy to hear that.

Comment: @HansPassant you're first saying "*Users like this always get caught, eventually, justice is merely delayed.*", then you make snide remarks about the alleged bot of Magisch that finds these offenders that go below the radar. This seems to me as if you were saying "*I shouldn't call the cops when I see a robbery; robbers are usually caught by cops anyway*". In what way is it harmful if there's one more channel for tracking down users who game the system? Cheaters are the bane of the quality of Stack Overflow (robo reviewers anyone?).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Does the serial voting script need retuning to keep up with the times?

I mentioned this in passing [a few months back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291152/so-long-sklivvz), but we've been collecting data on this for a few years now.

The technique used by the active scripts is pretty similar to the one you devised, albeit with much more conservative thresholds. The one used by the silent data-collection system is much more sensitive... But more importantly, it doesn't forget: I can go back three years and pick out a vote that was flagged as easily as I can look up votes from yesterday.

Which creates both an opportunity and a quandary:

- The big problem with the active scripts is that a sufficiently-motivated voter can readily learn to work around them: keep trying different voting patterns until their votes stop getting invalidated. The scripts then become ineffective... But that history remains, and chances are the silent system keeps tracking suspicious votes long after the active script gave up.
- There are a LOT of suspicious votes. 5-6% of all votes are flagged. Most of these are not particularly problematic; that time you downvoted two answers from the same person back-to-back could easily have been warranted. If we went & invalidated all of them... Well, [I did that a while back on a smaller site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15317/exchange-votes-or-favours/15520#15520) - it didn't go *too* badly, but convinced me to back to work on reducing false-positives.

There's also a third system... This is the one that brings specific users to the attention of moderators due to outlandishly unusual voting patterns. It uses a similar technique to the first system (and your script), but is much *less* conservative than both (however, it limits itself to the most blatant offenders). The data collected by the second, silent system is currently being used to reduce false-positives in the third system.

And then there's a fourth... Well, ok, it's not really a system so much as it is a collection of tools that I and the Cogro Ops team use when moderators escalate certain forms of fraud to the team. It's essentially everything I've learned about this in the past 5 years, codified in SQL and JavaScript. It's crazy-thorough, able to identify fraudulent votes that all of the other systems miss, and rarely has false-positives... It's also crazy-slow, because SQL sucks at doing things like traversing undirected graphs (and I suck at writing SQL).

### Modern times

Now, the obvious next move here is to take the data from that second system, establish some thresholds, and start automatically invalidating votes much more aggressively. The problem with doing that is two-fold: there'd be a lot more complaints about false-positives *and* it would immediately teach dedicated fraudsters how to avoid that system as well - thus making the third system less effective.

The more effective route is probably to automate what we're doing today: wait for the number of suspicious votes between users (as detected by the second system) to reach a critical level, then - let's say weekly or even monthly - invalidate them all at once. This would reduce false-positives *and* make it prohibitively time-consuming to work around.

However... There's another concern: if we make it too difficult to figure out what you're doing wrong, we also make it too difficult to stop doing it entirely. Right now, nearly half of all users who get votes invalidated by the automated systems *don't cause further voting anomalies* while still remaining active on the site.

### Interpersonal skills

Tim Post came up with a theory years ago that a sizable number of the folks engaging in this are simply trying to "fit in" to a group; they feel pressured socially to vote for their friends, co-workers, teachers, boss... Seeing those votes invalidated gives them an *out* - an excuse to *not* vote for this group when otherwise they'd come off like an ass if they refused.

In other words, the same behavior that makes the current system suck at stopping determined frausters also makes it effective at stopping casual fraud. It keeps mostly-honest people mostly-honest. We... Probably don't want to lose that.

One idea we've tossed around for a while is just implementing a simple warning: if the system notices that most of your recent votes have gone to the same person, ask you nicely to *stop doing that*.

[image: Other authors need love too]

Comment: *“One idea… implementing a simple warning: if the system notices that most of your recent votes have gone to the same person, ask you nicely to* stop doing that.” It’d be great to see that implemented. It’d also be good if that message linked to an explanation of why it’s bad in the context of SO—because it’s not at all necessarily intuitive/obvious to new users that serial upvoting is absolutely bad. It’s not something *universally* bad that other types of online fora need to discourage in their context. So it’d be a good thing socially for SO to really help users understand why it’s bad here

Comment: So my theory about you already having all that stuff is indeed correct.

Comment: I find it a little disturbing how much impressively complicated tooling and work it takes to stop people from doing something that takes a few clicks. Dealing with people is _hard_. Thanks for all the work you and the rest of the team do, by the way.

Comment: "People are a problem" -- Douglas Adams