# When is serial upvoting worth flagging?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

This is a corollary to my [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355966/just-how-conservative-is-the-voting-reversal-script?noredirect=1#comment510033_355966) meta question about the serial voting reversal script.

At what threshold and at what recency it is worth to flag serial upvoting that I find on other users' accounts?

For instance I found this:

[image: serial question upvoting]

Now this is obviously serial voting, and the automated script caught only 75 of the 200+ points the user obtained this way.

The problem is, it happened over 2 years ago.

So this got me thinking. There are literally thousands of cases like this, where conventional wisdom of "flag it if you see it" would mean I'd have to pester the moderation team with days worth of work sifting through these. We'd be talking a month or more of 100 flags a day to go through the backlog of just the last 3 years.

Is it worth for me to report 6-8 serial votes that happened years ago?  Sometimes people go "mild" on serial voting and don't go upvoting 20+ posts at once, but only 6 or 7 at once.

I understand mods have to escalate all of these flags, and CMs have to manually review each case, so I'm hesitant to flag in mass. I don't want to cost the community team and moderators more than the entire endeavour is worth.

So my question is:

**Is there any official guidance about when serial voting matters enough to be worth reporting?** Ideally looking for community discussion and maybe an official answer on the topic.

Comment: Do you just randomly come across these users or is there an automated way of finding potential abusers? (except for the reversal script)

Comment: @Keiwan I sort of made my own automated way. I don't want to air this way publicly to stop myself from inciting a witch hunt.

Comment: Get out the stakes, brushwood and torches.  I mean, witch-hunts are only bad if the victims are not actually casting spells for poor crops and plagues.

Comment: It would be nice if you could somehow get together with a mod and privately give them a data dump of these potential abusers so that they could then act accordingly. That way none of these cases would end up as individual flags in the moderator review queues but instead they'd be batched together for the mods to go through (which I'm assuming should be a lot more efficient for the moderators)

Comment: @Keiwan That wouldn't solve that a CM would have to review each individual case, though. And moderators already have the ability to access my data, it's just more convenient for them if I pre-review it, since there are some false positives and some instances that have already been dealt with.

Comment: Well, do you have to flag them all at the same time??  That is no fun for anybody, not you and not the mods.  You could just run your query once a week and pick-off, say, the top 10 posts.  Do the sensible thing.

Comment: @Magisch awesome work BTW. I'm sure mods are interested by the top 10 wrongly upvoted users.

Comment: It's a really difficult question. On the one hand this would generate unnecessary work when you continuously flag cases where someone was smugly sprinkling some thanks on a person. But on the other hand if you don't flag then that is less chance of repeat offenders being sniffed out - the true _serial_ upvoting cases.

Comment: @HansPassant There are around 25-40 new cases per week. So if I always picked the top 10 posts I'd not only never catch up, I'd fall further behind.

Comment: It's probably sock puppet accounts. The easiest way to get rep when you think getting rep is a goal. worth flagging and deleting/suspending the accounts of the offenders.

Comment: Sigh, then do not flag new cases, this job is not your sole responsibility.  I flag such cases too when I run into them, no doubt many other users do as well.  It is just not instantaneous and there is no need for it to be.  If you don't know how to make this a reasonable effort then just don't do it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Some of these cases are really historical.  Probably best to avoid deleting/suspending Jon Skeet 'cos someone serial-upvoted him  in '09 :)

Comment: Okay to leave John Skeet out of it !

Comment: Folks a response from us is coming on this, hang tight (and please don't flag these in huge batches until we've had an opportunity to share some guidance). As Brad said, current voting rings with _long tail_ histories really do need priority here, what someone got from sharing a link on twitter to 2k followers 2 years ago is probably benign. These aren't always as clear as they might seem, and could easily overwhelm the mods if they come in mass flag waves. Hang tight :)

Comment: @TimPost I also sent a contact us ticket with all the instructions of how I did it and the where/what/how in accordance to Martijn's advice. And yeah, I'm not going ahead and spending hours to flag hundreds of users without explicit permission, I like my helpful rate above 99% :D. I also haven't shared the method publicly yet on purpose, to avoid y'all getting flag bombed by eager participants.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran your script on internal data with the default options and compared the results to those of [the second system mentioned here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355966/just-how-conservative-is-the-voting-reversal-script/355999#355999). Your script identified two users who were missed by the internal tool.

This suggests that there's no particular urgency: if and when we want to clean up these votes, we likely already have sufficient data on 99% of them without needing flags.

What's lacking is the time to weed out false-positives. As Brad mentioned, we do this by hand right now; moderators review flags, review the users identified, and either act or escalate; if they escalate, then at least one person on the team (possibly multiple) review the votes before finally invalidating. We do this because we tend to consider it a lot more important to avoid driving away people by carelessly invalidating votes than to reduce small-scale fraud.

Of course...ideally we'd accomplish both goals. Over the past year, you've tried a few different approaches to finding these: as a result, your success rate has gotten a lot better. You're not the first person to use the basic approach exhibited in your latest script, but the thresholds you've chosen appear to avoid a lot of the false-positives normally seen (and which make these so tedious to handle).

So to answer your question...focus on recent events. Catching them stands to do a lot more good, but more importantly, they're much more effective at letting you hone your tools, and helping us hone ours.

Comment: Do you consider it generally worth moderators and your time if I flag new cases weekly? (the ones that happened in the preceding week)

Comment: Also, I haven't exactly spent a year on it, I just used to use a script that someone else made and linked me to once. I started this month to make my own, however after getting a feel of how inaccurate said script was and how many it missed :)

Answer (score 15):

In general, I prefer to focus on current problems first. If someone is operating a voting ring that is inflating the votes on new posts, we'll want to stop that. Our tools are oriented towards finding recent voting anomalies, with less of an emphasis on older incidents.

Once we've worked through the most recent cases, then we'll maybe start stepping back to find cases that were missed in the last month, six months, etc. While I do value keeping the score honest for all posts, I don't know if it's a high priority to go back and manually correct voting on posts for incidents that happened years ago. The voting will usually have normalized over time so that those fraudulent votes won't have that much of an impact on overall score.

For clear sock puppets, it's easy for us to delete them whenever the voting had happened, so I'll act on those even years later. If you see an account named John Smith only asking questions for another account named John Smith to answer, that might be worth letting us know about even if it happened a while ago. That's easy for us to clean up.

When we're talking about two or more actual users directing votes at one another, we have to decide if that's worth escalating to SE employees to review. My general thinking on this is that it's not worth it on rings more than a year old unless the ring size is large enough. If there is any recent voting activity in the ring, that would also make it worth reporting. I know, it's irritating to see someone get away with a little cheating, but moderators and SE employees have a limited amount of time and ongoing problems are a higher priority.

Also, when reviewing these older cases make sure that action hasn't already been taken. Many people have flagged older serial voting cases without noticing that the votes had been corrected years ago. I'm pretty sure you're catching these, but some people haven't been as careful when reviewing reputation histories like this.

Answer (score 4):

## ***All*** cases of voting fraud should be reversed if confirmed, regardless of age

Voting is the fundamental metric upon which the site is built. Voting fraud<sup>1</sup> is unacceptable. Any such cases which you reasonably suspect should be reported and reviewed by those with access to the information to make an actual determination. This should happen regardless of how long ago the voting fraud occurred. While we might decide that there is a statue of limitations on being *punished* for voting fraud, there is none for reversing ill-gotten gains (upvoting) or correcting the loss from fraudulent downvoting.

### Use other methods for bulk reporting

The normal way to report such things is to flag for moderator attention using a custom flag. However, given that there are literally thousands of cases which you've identified, it's probably desirable to transfer the information in some way other than individually flagging.

The obvious alternatives for communicating the information are:

- Flags
- A Meta post
- Using the "[contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact)" link

You will have to wait for a response indicating how it's desired to communicate such a large quantity of information. The most likely is either a flag with a pointer to the data/tools or using the "contact us" link. Frankly, this situation sounds like one where the best solution is for people to work together to find a solution, as opposed to you just submitting thousands of flags which can have relatively little context given the nature of flags (limited characters for description).

#### Probably desirable to provide tools

Personally, if I were a CM that was going to be reviewing these, I would want to be informed of them in bulk and have access to the tools you are using to find these cases (I assume it's SEDE queries). Having access to those tools would allow the CM to build upon that code, incorporating private information which is unavailable in SEDE. Having access to to the tool(s) you are using would allow them not to have to begin from scratch. It would also allow them to add additional criteria, based on private information, to automatically filter out cases which should not be considered. Obviously, it also permits them to filter *in* additional cases which might be easily identifiable with access to private information.

Having the tool(s) in the hands of the person/people performing the actual review would allow them to more efficiently handle the cases in bulk, rather than have to handle each case in isolation. While each case certainly deserves to be individually considered, at the volume of a few/several thousand identified instances, it is *very* helpful to be able to refine the automatic review to the extent reasonably possible. Doing so should provide the most time-efficient method (from everyone's point of view) of handling this flood of cases.

### Age, priority and time to review/correct

The review and reversal should occur regardless of age. However, it should be clear that something like this, which has existed on the site for years, should be given a lower priority than more immediate, pressing concerns. Thus, I would not be surprised if full review/correction of so many cases stretched out over many weeks, or months.

---

<sup>1. Voting fraud defined broadly as both actual fraud (e.g. sockpuppets) and voting in patterns which are considered unacceptable to the community (e.g. serial up- or down-voting).</sup>

Comment: No one is disputing that all voting fraud should be invalidated. The problem here is *identifying* that fraud in the first place.

Comment: @BoltClock, I don't mean to imply that anyone, other than the OP, was questioning if suspected voter fraud should be investigated. The Question (both the question title and question text) could be paraphrased as "should I bother reporting older findings *at all*". Magisch was also [questioning in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=38938685#38938685) *if* they should report, not just *how* to do so. Yes, there are significant issues with identifying *actual* fraud. That doesn't change that such suspected fraud should be reported/communicated, which is the base Question.

Comment: They basically *are* being reported in bulk and handled in batches. I mean, it's not that difficult to sort the flag queue and pick out what Magisch has flagged, and then when moderators escalate to the community team, they look through the messages and handle them at once. So the reporting process is not the problem, it's the sheer quantity and a question of whether it's really worth the effort. Philosophically, I agree with you that all vote fraud should be reversed, regardless of age. Practically, I'm less convinced that it's worth the time. There are many more pressing issues.

Comment: I mean, think about this...Yesterday, there were about as many plagiarism flags in the queue as there were vote fraud allegations. Even if you suppose that both flags have exactly the same "hit rate" (i.e., no false positives), plagiarism takes less time to investigate and can be handled completely by moderators with no CM involvement. Plus, I think addressing plagiarism is a lot more important than ~5 erroneous votes on a user. When you have limited time and resources, you have to make choices. Which flag type do you think I chose to handle? Which one would you have chosen to prioritize?

Comment: I'm less then convinced that invalidating votes from multiple years ago is a good use of CM ressources. Many of these users maybe got away with like 100 reputation of serial votes. That's regrettable sure but I'm not going to start issuing like 1500+ flags per year I go back for vote invalidations. In the meantime, CMs are very busy and so are moderators, and I'm not about to make them violently angry with me by drowning them with that time joe schmoe got 100 illicit reputation in 2013. Like @CodyGray said, there are higher priorities, I think.

Comment: @CodyGray, I agree that, of course, things need to be prioritized; limited resources have to be allocated and choices must be made when those resources don't cover everything we'd like to do. But, the Question isn't "how should moderators, or SE prioritize investigation of voting fraud". The Question boils down to "What is the cutoff (in age and # votes) at which point *users* shouldn't bother to report serial upvoting." What are the levels of age and # of votes at which you are wanting to say: "We've decided in advance that we don't care about that. We don't want to even hear about it."?

Comment: @Makyen I think it's more "we've decided that we have too much to do to do that yet. And my question isn't necessarily about someone stumbling upon this and reporting it, it's about If I should bother systematically flagging my backlog of thousands of cases, to which the answer is probably not.